# Cannot delete version

Tags: google-app-engine

I cannot stop or delete versions of a project created as it was created as a flexible environment within the EU. I understand the restriction by region but cannot work out why it cannot be removed.

```
jamie@dartmoor-1320:~$ gcloud preview app versions delete 20160607t131220
Deleting the following versions:
 - dartmoor-1320/default/20160607t131220
Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  
Deleting [default/20160607t131220]...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.versions.delete) Issue deleting version: [default/20160607t131220]
[default/20160607t131220]: Error Response: [13] Managed VMs can not be hosted in the application's region. (e~))
```

The GUI fails too but with a non descript error message.

Comment: do you have any other version for default module?

Comment: 4 - they were created as I was playing. I want rid of all of it as they will not work until flexible environments work in EU

Comment: `SERVICE  VERSION          TRAFFIC_SPLIT  LAST_DEPLOYED              SERVING_STATUS
default  20160607t113333  1.00           2016-06-07T11:35:20+01:00  STOPPED
default  20160607t113816  0.00           2016-06-07T11:38:49+01:00  SERVING
default  20160607t115306  0.00           2016-06-07T12:00:30+01:00  SERVING
default  20160607t131220  0.00           2016-06-07T13:13:17+01:00  SERVING`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have to have *at least* one version for the default module. That's the reason why it doesn't allow you to delete it.

You need to deploy a new version, it can be a Flexible VM (deployed to another region in your situation), or Standard VM.

As a workaround, when you don't have any app to replace it right now, you can deploy an empty app instead. You have to create an `app.yaml`:

```
---
runtime: python38
handlers:
  - url: /
    script: auto
```

and deploy it using:

```
gcloud app deploy app.yaml
```

As your `app.yaml` doesn't have any script to execute, you'll not be charged for any instance.

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful. What if I just want to remove the app completely until I have something genuine to put up? Everything I have says that I cannot delete the default module. Can I get back to when I had no App Engine stuff on this project?

Comment: You can delete whole google project, there is a special button in Cloud Console for this. That also means that Project ID assigned to the project cannot be reused later when you'll decide to create project again (that's in case if you set it manually, not just a random generated id)

Comment: I see. OK, I have data in some buckets that I want to keep that are within the project so I will need to keep it. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Empty module will be free for your (unless someone will decide to download million copies of your index.html, at this case you'll pay for traffic :)

Comment: It says `preview` is not an option!

Comment: What a ridiculous requirement! Especially because there are billing options related to this.... I see my stopped app is still using resources somehow (ram apparently).

Comment: @Raptor oh yeah, it's `gcloud app deploy` now

Comment: This answer is also what the GCP Support suggested in 2014. I don't understand why they didn't add this function yet? It feels like a hack rather than a solution :( https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/YqtwpjaIhKQ

Comment: OMG, this is so unreal and disrespectful!!! This is why aws and azure are so more popular than gcp...

Answer (score 6):

If you want to stop app engine you can disable it **App Engine -> Settings -> Disable application**

This will only stop traffic to you Application after that you can remove the instances.

Comment: It still don't let me remove the instances, even while disabled.

Comment: Be aware, disabling of app engine also disables datastore

Comment: It still don't let me remove the instances, even while disabled.

Comment: this is completely untrue

Answer (score 0):

The version you are trying to delete may have some errors with it.

What worked for me was uploading a new version that I knew doesn't have errors and migrating to it. After that, I was able to delete the un-deletable version.