# How to release a global static IP

Tags: google-compute-engine, billing

I am being billed for an unused IP address. I can't find the item that's
charging me.

I've gone through the project using console.cloud.google.com looking in Compute Engine and Networking settings, but I can't find any IP addresses.

I'm only using the project for Cloud Storage of 1 text file, and a git
repository. I run these commands on the terminal, and I am getting 0 items.

```
$ gcloud --project=PROJECTNAME compute addresses list
```

The above command listed 0 items.

```
$ gcloud --project=PROJECTNAME compute forwarding-rules list
```

The above command listed 0 items.

Is there a way of telling where this static IP address is, or how I
can disable it? I can't find it anywhere. I'd rather not delete the entire
project because some of the services are being used by my production app.

I know that it's a global IP address because I can see it listed in my
Compute Engine quota. For me to be able to use a command line option to delete the address, I think that I need the name of the address, but I can't find that listed anywhere.

I'm thinking this could be related to me having one of these two
things enabled for the project in the past:

1. I was running an AppEngine project, but have since terminated it.
2. For the AppEngine project, I registered a custom domain to point
   to it.

Comment: the command **gcloud compute addresses list** should list the reserved static ip address. Make sure you are running in the correct project. If the problem persists, file a technical issue to GCP

Comment: Thanks. I've double checked, I'm definitely in the correct project. It seems like a technical issue.

Comment: It turns out that billing support was able to give me the name of the IP address, and I still wasn't able to release it using gcloud on the console using this command.

    `gcloud compute addresses delete aef-vip`

I was given the following error:

`ERROR: (gcloud.compute.addresses.delete) Some requests did not` `succeed:`
`- The resource 'projects/<project-name>/global/addresses/aef-vip'` 
`was not found`

I have tried creating a new default app and removing the previous one.

Comment: Bryan - did you find a solution? I've got the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had used AppEngine Flexible (aef). The unused IP was from my stopped version. This blocks the releasing of the static IP and so it was advised to first delete this version before trying to release the IP address again.

You cannot delete your previous version if that's the only one you have as you need to have at least one version for the default module.

To fix you could deploy a new version, say a Flexible VM (deployed to another region), or a Standard VM. Then as a workaround, if you do not have any app to replace it right now, you can deploy an empty app instead. You would need to create an app.yaml that uses only static files that does not have any script to execute so you would not be charged for any instance.

For a more detailed guide in doing this workaround, you may check this documentation [1].

[1] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37679552/cannot-delete-version